# How to preserve homemade fresh cream for about a week in a freezer?

Tags: storage-method, storage-lifetime, refrigerator, cream, storage

I get the full cream milk, boil it, and then let it cool down. I collect the thick layer of cream that gathers on its top and put it in the freezer in a vessel.

Next day if I get more milk I again follow the same process and put the new cream in the already stored cream vessel in the freezer.

What should I do to extend the lives of these creams such that they last for about a week?

Comment: Do you mean the fridge or the freezer? Your question body says "freezer", and Elendil's answer assumes it too, but the title says "fridge" and it is likely it will go off there.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the milk is pasteurised, frozen cream made with it should last for months in a clean, sealed container in the freezer. I would put each batch in a separate container though rather than putting room temperature cream in with already frozen.

Comment: why is "sealed" vessel needed? Moreover some link to support your claim would be helpful. no offense intended.

Comment: If it isn't sealed then the fat will pick up funky flavors from the air pretty quickly.

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius see here: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep it sealed for two reasons.

First, everytime you add new cream, you are warming the top layer of the frozen cream, and constant temp changes will damage the consistency of the cream.  So freeze separately.

Secondly, by not sealing, you are exposing it to the oxidation and dehydrating elements of a freezer, you'll get 'freezerburn' on your cream...which I gotta think is a not lovely result given the work you are putting into it.

Seal it in containers or plastic bags, whatever, and it will keep for months.

Answer (score 0):

My dad does the exact same thing in India and he keeps it covered with a lid in the freezer if not sealed. And the cream does last for months like @ElendilTheTall suggested.

The only other thing to consider is if electricity is a problem and there are power failures. Then the type of refrigerator comes into picture and whether yours is a frost type or the defrost type. If it indeed builds up enough frost/ice in the freezer that it can sustain the cool in the freezer while the power failure is fixed, you shouldn't have much of a problem with the cream. But, if not, you should try to use the cream in short intervals.

Of course, if you do not have an electricity problem, the cream should last for months without problems.